# 'Send email as' - Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange, outlook

I have the need to send email as a different user.  My main email is user@domain.com, however I need to send email as user@domain1.com

I have incoming email working...if I send to user@domain.com or user@domain1.com, the email shows up in Outlook and all is well  (Outlook 2016)

However, if I compose a new email, change the "From" to user@domain1.com and hit send, I get a bounce

```
This message could not be sent. Try sending the message again later, or contact your network administrator. You do not have the permission to send the message on behalf of the specified user. Error is [0x80070005-0x0004dc-0x000524].
```

Searching on Google indicates that I need to allow permission to do this in Exchange, but always seems to point to the fact that I need to allow permissions to another user...but since that user is me and doesn't have a separate account, I don't understand how to make that work.

Comment: is the user@domain1.com listed as an alias? try `"from name"<user@domain1.com>;`

Answer (score 0):

That is how Exchange is designed to work.
As far as Exchange is concerned you have one email address - the default. Any other addresses are aliases which are for inbound email only. You cannot pick and choose the address.

You have a number of options depending on whether you are the server admin.

1. A third party tool called Choosefrom from ivasoft.biz.
2. A second mailbox. This is the preferred option. You can add the additional account in Outlook, get notification, different rules, signatures etc. Grant Send As and Full Mailbox permissions to the primary user and the secondary account can be disabled.
3. Dummy POP3 account in Outlook. Not a great solution in my opinion and not one I recommend. Can cause issues with where the email is stored.

As an end user, option 3 is the only one available to you. If you are the admin of the server then option 2 is the best available.

Comment: That's sort of what I was resolved to.  I assume that #2 consumes an Exchange license?

Comment: don't forget to cite your source,  http://exchangepedia.com/2007/04/how-to-send-as-alternate-email-address.html

Comment: Why do I need to cite a source? There isn't one - it came from my own knowledge. I have been an Exchange MVP for over ten years - I don't need to Google for solutions - I create them.

And the solution does NOT consume an Exchange licence. Most Exchange servers are licenced per user or per seat, and the additional shared mailbox doesn't consume a licence. Hosted platforms may vary.